# Como receber uma lista de parâmetros em uma propriedade corretamente?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datepicker

Estou usando esta biblioteca de widgets: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker

A biblioteca possibilita desabilitar determinadas datas dentro de um calendário. Originalmente no código documentado original, as datas canceladas só permitiam serem adicionadas com aproximação da data atual. Estas datas são passadas por parâmetros de uma lista.

```
listDateDisabled: [
                          DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)),
                          DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 4)),
                          DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6)),
                          DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 8)),
                          DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 10)),
                          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)),
                          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 4)),
                          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 6)),
                          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 8)),
                          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 10)),
                        ]);
```

Consegui passar datas específicas para a lista

```
listDateDisabled: [
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-10"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-11"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-10"),
    ],
```

Acredito que o objetivo de bloquear datas já agendadas vindas de uma API está evidente. O problema é que quando transformo essa lista em uma variável ou uma função, a aplicação é compilada, mas o widget não carrega, seja como Lista local ou global.

```
var disableDays = [
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-10"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-11"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-12"),
    ];
...
...
listDateDisabled: disableDays;
```

Dentre as tentativas para inserir estes parâmetros (ou desabilitar os dias no calendário), estiveram:

- Adicionar item na lista usando forEach
- Criar função global que retorna a lista
- Tentei inserir diferente tipos de dados na lista
- Sem conseguir passar os parametros para a propriedade, tentei usar o calendário nativo da API do dart usando a função selectableDayPredicate . Usei este tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647938/how-to-disable-list-of-specific-date-on-flutter . Mas não consegui implementar a solução.
- Pesquisar por data desabilitada nas documentações

Nas tentativas envolvendo código, o widget não foi carregado na tela, e não consigo passar uma lista de dados como parâmetro. Isso aparenta ser um problema de funções síncronas e assíncronas, mas não sei trabalhar com estes conceitos no flutter. Tenho consciência que há dois problemas aqui: O técnico, que é a passagem de parâmetros em forma de lista, e o de regra de negócios que é desabilitar datas de um calendário. Mesmo recebendo a solução da regra de negócios (talvez nos comentários), gostaria de conseguir resolver o problema técnico para que outros não passem por este problema.

Código final:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/flutter_rounded_date_picker.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/src/material_rounded_date_picker_style.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/src/material_rounded_year_picker_style.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DateTime dateTime;
  Duration duration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateTime = DateTime.now();
    duration = Duration(minutes: 10);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List> processaDias() {
    List result = "nada";
    return result;
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _buildBody() {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Date Time selected",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "$dateTime",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Duration Selected",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "$duration",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              children: <Widget>[
                //const SizedBox(height: 16),

                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    DateTime newDateTime = await showRoundedDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
                        imageHeader: AssetImage(
                          "assets/images/calendar_header_rainy.jpg",
                        ),
                        fontFamily: "Mali",
                        description:
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                        listDateDisabled: [
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-10"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-11"),
      DateTime.parse("2021-03-12"),
    ],
                        );
                    if (newDateTime != null) {
                      setState(() => dateTime = newDateTime);
                    }
                  },
                  label: const Text("Rounded Calendar and Custom Font"),
                ),

                //const SizedBox(height: 12),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Rounded Date Picker'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        child: _buildBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Na verdade, o problema do seu código é na função `processaDias()` - ele está com erro de compilação. Corrigindo esse problema, migrando seu método para uma função assíncrona (repare no `async` no final do método) e inicializando `result` como uma lista de strings, o seu código funciona inclusive com as datas desabilitadas.

Sua função corrigida:

```
Future<List> processaDias() async {
    List result = ["nada"];
    return result;
}
```

Seu código rodando:

[image: Código rodando]